# Bash/Awk: Reformat uneven columns with multiple deliminators

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a CSV where I need to reformat a single column's contents.
The problem is that each cell has completely different lengths to reformat.

Current column looks like (these are two lines of single column) :

```
Foo*foo*foo*1970,1980+Bar*bar*bar*1970
Foobar*Foobar*foobarbar*1970,1975,1980
```

Result should look like (still two lines one column)

```
Foo*foo*foo*1970+Foo*foo*foo*1980+Bar*bar*bar*1970
Foobar*Foobar*foobarbar*1970+Foobar*Foobar*foobarbar*1975+Foobar*Foobar*foobarbar*1980
```

this is what I'm trying to do

```
#!/bin/bash

cat foocol | \
    awk -F'+' \
    '{for i in NF print $i}' \
        | awk -F'*' \
        '{$Foo=$1"*"$2"*"$3"*" print $4}' \
\
        | awk -v Foo=$Foo -F',' \
        '{for j in NF do \
            print Foo""$j"+" }' \
> newcol
```

The idea is to iterate over the multiple '+' delimited data, while the first three '*' delimited values are to be grouped for every ',' delimited year, with a '+' between them

But I'm just getting syntax errors everywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk --re-interval -F, -v OFS=+ '{match($1,/([^*]*\*){3}/);
                 prefix=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); 
                 for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) $i=prefix $i }1' file

Foo*foo*foo*1970+Foo*foo*foo*1980+Bar*bar*bar*1970  
Foobar*Foobar*foobarbar*1970+Foobar*Foobar*foobarbar*1975+Foobar*Foobar*foobarbar*1980
```

perhaps add validation with `if(match(...`

Answer (score 1):

Solution in [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr):

```
$ txr reformat.txr  data
Foo*foo*foo*1970+Foo*foo*foo*1980+Bar*bar*bar*1970
Foobar*Foobar*foobarbar*1970+Foobar*Foobar*foobarbar*1975+Foobar*Foobar*foobarbar*1980
```

Code in `reformat.txr`:

```
@(repeat)
@  (coll)@/\+?/@a*@b*@c*@(coll)@{x /[^,+]+/}@(until)+@(end)@(end)
@  (output :into items)
@    (repeat)
@      (repeat)
@a*@b*@c*@x
@      (end)
@    (end)
@  (end)
@  (output)
@    {items "+"}
@  (end)
@(end)
```

This solution is based on regarding the data to have nested syntax: groups of records are delimited by newlines. Records within groups are separated by `+` and within records there are four fields separated by `*`. The last field contains comma-separated items. The data is to be normalized by expanding copies of the records such that the comma-separated items are distributed across the copies.

The outer `@(repeat)` handles walking over the lines. The outer `@(coll)` iterates over records, collecting the first three fields into variables `a`, `b` and `c`. Then an inner `@(coll)` gets each comma separated item into the variable `x`. The inner `@(coll)` collects the `x`-s into a list, and the outer `@(coll)` also collects all the variables into lists, so `a`, `b`, `c` become lists of strings, and `x` is a list of lists of strings.

The `:into items` keyword parameter in the `output` causes the lines which would normally go the standard output device to be collected into a list of strings, and bound to a variable. For instance:

```
@(output :into lines)
a
b
cd
@(end)
```

establishes a variable `lines` which contains the list `("a" "b" "cd")`.

So here we are getting the output of the doubly-nested `repeat` as a bunch of lines, where each line represents a record, stored in a variable called `items`. Then we `output` these using the `@{items "+"}`, a syntax which outputs the contents of a list variable with the given separator.

The doubly nested `repeat` handles the expansion of records over each comma separated item from the fourth field. The outer `repeat` implicitly iterates over the lists `a`, `b`, `c` and `x`. Inside the `repeat`, these variables denote the items of their respective lists. Variable `x` is a list of lists, and so the inner `repeat` iterates over that. Inside the outer `repeat`, variables `a`, `b`, `c` are already scalar, and stay that way in the scope of the inner `repeat`: only `x` varies, which is exactly what we want.

In the data collection across each line, there are some subtleties:

```
@  (coll)@/\+?/@a*@b*@c*@(coll)@{x /[^,+]+/}@(until)+@(end)@(end)
```

Firstly, we match an optional leading plus with the `/\+?/` regex, thereby consuming it. Without this, the `a` field of every record, except for the first one, would include that separating `+` and we would get double `+`-s in the final output.  The `a`, `b`, `c` variables are matched simply. TXR is non-greedy with regard to the separating material: `@a*` means match some characters up to the nearest `*` and bind them to a variable `a`. Collecting the `x` list is more tricky. Here was use a positive-regex-match variable: `@{x /[^,+]+/}` to extract the sub-field. Each `x` is a sequence of one or more characters which are not pluses or commas, extracted positively without regard for whatever follows, much like a tokenizer extracts a token.  This inner collect terminates when it encounters a `+`, which is what the `@(until)+` clause ensures. It will also implicitly terminate if it hits the end of the line; the `@(until)` match isn't mandatory (by default). That terminating `+` stays in the input stream, which is why we have to recognize it and discard it in front of the `@a`.

It should be noted that `@(coll)`, by default, scans for matches and skips regions of text that do not match, just like its cousin `@(collect)` does with lines. For instance if we have `@(coll)@{foo /[a-z]+/}@(end)`, which collects sequences of lower-case letters into `foo`, turning `foo` into a list of such strings, and if the input is `1234abcd-efgh.... ijk`, then `foo` ends up with the list `("abcd" "efgh" "ijk")`. This is why there is no explicit logic in the inner `@(coll)` to consume the separating commas: they are implicitly skipped.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough and educating answer. I didn't know about TXR and it sounds interesting. Although @karakfa's answer wasn't explanatory, it didn't deviate from the question, and I implemented it successfully. Thus it makes sense that it will be the one I accept.
I will look into learning about the tool you kindly suggested.